# Rails Devise 2.0 own Log-out action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I use Devise and I want to do my logout action.

What I want to do is, that when I log out, I want to create a own JSON object to return. At this time, after I logt out, I get all my root articles.

How can I write my own destory action like I have found the create action?

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => :failure)
    return sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    resource ||= resource_or_scope
    sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
    return render :json => {:success => true, :redirect => stored_location_for(scope) || after_sign_in_path_for(resource)}
  end

  def failure
    return render:json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
  end

end
```

And my Routes in routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:session => "sessions"} do
    get "/users/sing_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the destroy method of the sessions-controller.

you should be able to customize it to your needs. i think that it would be wiser to add another action and implementing your custom behavior there, as this will be less likely to cause unexpected errors with upgrading devise in the future.

```
  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    redirect_path = after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out

    # We actually need to hardcode this as Rails default responder doesn't
    # support returning empty response on GET request
    respond_to do |format|
      format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to redirect_path }
      format.all do
        method = "to_#{request_format}"
        text = {}.respond_to?(method) ? {}.send(method) : ""
        render :text => text, :status => :ok
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: no this does not work for me, my problem is, that i have now my own class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController but how can i redirect logins and logouts to my sessioncontroller ?

Comment: if you have a sessions controller in your application it should respond to all the requests, you should not need to do any redirecting to it.

Comment: Okai, I have removed the routing to the session controller, but it still does not work. My sessions_controller.rb looks like the class that I have posted. What do i wrong?